# Why this function not printing all substrings of string s?

Tags: c++

I am trying to print all substring of string but this function not printing all substring can you explain whats wrong?

require o/p= >

```
a
ab
abc
b
bc
c
```

curr o/p=>

```
a
ab
abc
b
```

```
void subString(string s, int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int len = 1; len <= n - i; len++) {

            string str;

            for (int k = i; k < len; k++) {
                str += s[k];
            }
            if (str != "")
                cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that by `string` you mean `std::string` as defined in the `<string>` header?

Comment: The expected solution here should have exactly two `for` loops. Not three. The shown logic must be fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Does the argument `n` indicate the length of the string `s`?  You could just get that using `s.size()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The third one just copies char from one string into another.  There may be more efficient ways to do this, but it doesn't look like flawed logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k` is initialized with `i` (trying to use index in overall string), but the loop condition is compared to `len` (trying to use index in current substring). This is contradiction. Use either one index.

Use index in overall string:

```
            for (int k = i; k < i + len; k++) {
                str += s[k];
            }
```

Use index in current substring:

```
            for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                str += s[i + k];
            }
```

Another way is to use the standard [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) (assuming `string` here is `std::string`):

```
            str = s.substr(i, len);
```